# One SQL statement to deal with both NULL and a STRING possibility for same value

Tags: php, mysql, string, null

I have a strange situation I have never run into before.
I am calling data from an API and updating my database to match exactly. An issue arises when the value comes back `NULL`.

My SQL statement:

```
$update_entry = "UPDATE clientpatientrelationships SET APILastChangeDate=$APILastChangeDate WHERE Id='$Id'";
```

The reason I have no quotes around the `$APILastChangeDate` variable, is because to use `NULL`, I cant use single quotes. But when the value is a string, it needs the quotes. Here lies my issue. Also, part of my issue is the need for triple equal sign when setting a variable to `NULL`.

I can get each of the following individual statements to work one at a time:

```
$APILastChangeDate="'0000-00-29 00:00:00'";
$update_entry = "UPDATE clientpatientrelationships SET APILastChangeDate=$APILastChangeDate WHERE Id='$Id'";
```

And

```
$APILastChangeDate===NULL;
$update_entry = "UPDATE clientpatientrelationships SET APILastChangeDate=$APILastChangeDate WHERE Id='$Id'";
```

With out the triple equal sign, the `NULL` value will not work when inside a variable. But, with triple quotes, the string value will not work.

I am trying to write a single function to handle all of this, but I cant figure out the `===` along with the quotes or no quotes.

My function:

```
function null_test($value)
{
    if (is_null($value)){
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return "'".$value."'";
    }
}
```

Since the value coming back from the API might be `NULL` or, say, 25 - I cant figure out how to write a single function with a single update statement to handle this.

The only way I have gotten this to work is to use two different update statements with an IF clause to test `if(is_null($value))`.

I have done research on google, but to no avail. Is it possible to handle both a `NULL` or a string in one SQL statement?

Comment: You should consider using a mysql prepared statement. You will fix both the null and security issues :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Have you tried using the php string `"NULL"` rather than the php value `null`?

Comment: I did not write this project.. prepared statements would require rewriting more then I have been asked to do, or have time for.. I agree it would solve the issue tho..

Comment: Double quotes will exit the query.

Comment: Right. But you want to see mysql something like `SET x = null` so you need to construct that string in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with php some years ago, when I built queries, I always used sprintf, it's a good way to build queries in php and you can use str_replace to replace the value `'NULL'` for `NULL`. You have to do something like this:

```
$arrayNulls = ("'null'", "'NULL'");

$query = sprintf ("UPDATE clientpatientrelationships SET APILastChangeDate='%s' WHERE Id='%s'", $APILastChangeDate, $Id);

$query = str_replace($arrayNulls, "NULL", $query);
```

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.